# Populate share button dynamically from DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a standalone share button - where I would like to populate the share window with a video link. I need to do this dynamically since the link changes - can I do this somehow by targeting the "selected" class on the HTML snippet below? It now shares the site as per the example, how do I change the site location to the videolink?

Button:

```
<a class="faceshare" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://example.com" target="_blank">
```

HTML:

```
<li class="feed-item selected"><div class="thumbnail-excerpt wprss-feed-thumbnail">
 <a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bj_N5o_-P_A"><img src="wp-content/uploads/cache/remote/i3-ytimg-com/3718811643.jpg" height="280" width="280">
 </a><
</li>
```

This is the closest I got so far - it shows my link changed in the console, but doesn't change in the DOM.

The result in console is

```
"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bj_N5o_-P_A"
```

Script

```
var link = jQuery('li.feed-item.selected a.colorbox.cboxElement').attr('href');
jQuery('a.faceshare').attr("href").replace('https://example.com', link)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like
`$(".cboxElement").attr("href", "youLinkGoesHere")`

UPDATE:
A complete version of the answer is available here http://jsfiddle.net/y70zrm2s/3/

Comment: Not sure If I follow. I need to get the href link dynamically and then replace the https://example.com link

Comment: $(".cboxElement").attr("href").replace('example.com', 'yourLink')

Comment: hm, strange, the above did not work, however next did $('.link').each(function(){  this.href = this.href.replace('example.com', 'yourLink'); });

Comment: hmm I cant get that to work. Could you show in a fiddle?

Comment: have you replaced $('.link') with your class name in my second comment before trying it? 
Anyway the answer located in jsfiddle is better, without an extra 'each' loop

Comment: you mean the value to replace is dynamic? in this case you just need to use regexp to find value following 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' and replace it

Comment: Take a look on the updated version here http://jsfiddle.net/y70zrm2s/
It uses not regexp but just 'split'. If you look on the result link, it has also changed.

Comment: The fiddles are the same?

Comment: Yes, I can see that the link has changed. But how do I pull it dynamically from the .selected elements link? ?

Comment: Just replace in my example "123" with $('.selected a.cboxElement').attr('href')

Comment: here is an updated version with your markup http://jsfiddle.net/y70zrm2s/2/

Comment: and here is a version with regexp http://jsfiddle.net/y70zrm2s/3/ and it is more save in terms of possible errors while referring to an array element